# What does the % symbol mean in Android's material design button style?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button

I'm trying to implement an Android button with a raised-button style.

Under Google's Material Design Section on [flat and raised button states](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons), it gives a visual and then some details used to implement the design:

```
Flat Light/Light theme  
Minimum width: 88dp
Height: 36dp
Hover: 20% #999999
Pressed: 40% #999999
Disabled text: 26% #000000
```

For the hover and pressed state, what does the % symbol represent?
Which property does it refer to?

Comment: It refers to opacity. For Hover and Pressed, it's the opacity of the background,  For Disabled Text, it's the opacity of the text.

Comment: @MikeM. That makes sense.  Was that detail directly given, inferred, or left out of Google's Design spec?  I'm trying to gauge my resourcefulness or lack thereof.

Comment: Inferred. I haven't read every word of the Material Design spec, but I don't recall it being explicitly stated anywhere. If you read the section on Colors, I believe it discusses the recommended opacities.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage sign `%` represents the **alpha value** of the shade,Like `26% #000000` has an equivalent of `rgba(0,0,0,2.6)`.